# Which is more acidic alcohol or ketone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, alcohols

I have read about it and i found that the alcohol is more acidic, but isn't the conjugate base produced from losing the alpha hydrogen of the ketone **more stable** ?!

The negative charge in this conjugate base is spread over the oxygen atom and the alpha carbon atom by ***resonance*** ( **charge is delocalized** ) as shown in the attached image.

[image: resonance structures of the conjugate base produced from ketone]

while in the conjugate base produced from the alcohol we see that the negative charge is carried **only** by the oxygen atom and **no resonance structures** which means that ketone should be more acidic since its conjugate base is more stable and it will easy be formed.

Comment: Resonance is only one factor when it comes to anion stability. For a more extreme example, consider HCl and acetic acid...

Comment: No, I want this example what makes a ketone less acidic than alcohol although the conjugate base of a ketone is more stable than the conjugate base of the alcohol by resonance .

Comment: It **isn’t** more stable. If the pKa is larger, then it’s a weaker acid, and the anion is less stable. No exceptions.

Comment: What makes an apple taste different from an orange?

Answer (score 1):

You are considering two different Hs. I mean: one is a $\ce{O-H}$ bond; the other is an $\ce{C-H}$ bond. 
You can't compare these two bonds. 
Yes, $pK_a$ of the alcohol is around 16/17 and $pK_a$ of the ketone is around 25/26, but are two bonds completely different.

Comment: no it is not about bonds at all H2O is more acidic than NH3 and here we are comparing OH bond with NH bond .

Comment: @AhmedHossam If not for enol / ketone tautomerism, and hydration equilibrium, you could perhaps simply compare them with alcohols, but their properties aren't nearly as simple as both you and Andrea seem to think.